# Get rid of strings containing a pattern within a file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

Within a linux file with the following content I want to get rid of everything starting with a specific pattern, which is `aws:` in this particular case:

```
aws:cloudformation:logical-id="somestring" Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www" aws:autoscaling:groupName="strings-and-numbers-012345" aws:cloudformation:stack-id="strings-and-numbers-012345" aws:cloudformation:stack-name="strings-and-numbers-012345"
```

The output I need is just: `Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"`; how do I do it?

Comment: "Everything starting with a specific pattern" is much too vague. What is "everything" supposed to be? The whole file, the whole line, a "word"? If a word, which characters are valid? What is supposed to happen with the delimiters?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' file

Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed 's/aws:[^ ]*//g' filename
```

Comment: Close.... but I would say: ```sed 's/.*Name=/Name=/' | sed 's/ aws://'```. Perhaps there's a way to have them both work together in a single sed call but that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!~/^aws:/)b=b(b==""?"":OFS)$i;print b;b=""}' file
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```

Explained:

```
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # iterate over every field
        if($i!~/^aws:/)            # if it doesn't start start with aws:
            b=b (b==""?"":OFS) $i  # buffer it to b with OFS
    print b                        # never stop iterating till the iterating is done and output
    b=""                           # reset buffer
}
```

Downside is, it prints an empty line if every field starts with an `aws:`. Avoid that with `if(b!="")` before the `print b`.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$s" 
aws:cloudformation:logical-id="somestring" Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www" aws:autoscaling:groupName="strings-and-numbers-012345" aws:cloudformation:stack-id="strings-and-numbers-012345" aws:cloudformation:stack-name="strings-and-numbers-012345"
```

With GNU Grep and Perl regex you can do:

```
$ echo "$s" | grep -Po '(\bName=.*?)(?=aws)'
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```

If the fields you are interested in are strictly positional, you can use `awk` or `cut` to print those positional fields:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '{print $2, $3, $4}'
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
$ echo "$s" | cut -d" " -f2-4
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```

To weed out any entries that start with `aws` you can use `perl`:

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -lane 'foreach (@F) {$s=$s."$_ " unless /^aws/} print "$s"'
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```

or

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -lane 'print join(" ", grep {!/^aws/} @F)'
Name="abc" Product="xyz" Role="www"
```